# How to handle dialog.dismiss in particular conditions?

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

Here is my problem,

I have a main menu in my app, this menu launch an activity named farm1.
When this farm1 is launched, I have a dialog that shows-up, it explain how to navigate between the current activity ( farm1 ) to the second activity, which is in fact the second part ( called farm2 ) of my farm1 activity.

I am using swipe and

```
StartActivity(farm1);
finish();
```

and

```
StartActivity(farm2);
finish();
```

As you can see, when I am navigating from farm2 to farm1, I start this activity and so, my dialog shows-up again !

And I dont want this to happen, I just want my dialog appear when the main menu activity call the farm1 activity.

Considering the fact that my dialog creation is in onCreate, here are my questions :

- Can I navigate between farm1 and farm 2 activity without having to start them again, so that my dialog dont show-up again.
- Can I make this dialog show only when farm1 is launched from my main menu activity ?

Comment: Please include some code, it'll make it easier to help.

Comment: Please post an excerpt of your code.  Also, can you frame this as a more general question?  Perhaps: "How to show a dialog only once?"

Comment: try to describe more details, especially in the relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Intent for sending flag from which you are starting farm1 Activity as:

**STEP 1:** Send Intent with flag from Main menu Activity when you are starting farm1 Activity as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mainmenu.this, farm1.class);
intent.putExtra("flag_from", "mainmenu");
startActivity(intent);
```

**STEP 2:** Receive intent in farm1 Activity onCreate method as:

```
public class farm1 extends Activity {
    String flag="";
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Recive Intent here
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if(extras !=null)
              flag  = extras.getString("flag_from");
            else
              flag="";
        }
        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            // Check here flag before showing Alert dialog
             if(flag=="mainmenu"){
                  // show alert here
               }
              else{
                // do some code here
              }
        }
```

You can also do this by using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Answer (score 0):

When starting the Activity farm1, create an [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) with an extra argument:

```
//Put this where you return to Farm1:
Intent intent = new Intent(Farm2.this, Farm1.class);
intent.putExtra("ignoredialog", true);
startActivity(intent);

//And this in the onCreate() of Farm1:
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
if( extras != null && extras.containsKey("ignoredialog") && 
    extras.getBoolean("ignoredialog") ){
    //Do not show dialog
}else{
    //Show dialog
}
```

However, a better solution would be to not call `finish()` when opening Farm2, this would leave Farm1 available in the background and it would resume from the current state when you close Farm2. This is generally the expected behaviour of Activities.

Comment: Thank you everybody ! If works perfectly with flag method !

Next time I will also post code line asked !

Comment: @user1876708 Glad to be of help! If the answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted (by clicking the checkmark to the left) to close the question.